# Button to grab what's in the input and send a POST request

Tags: reactjs

I have an input field that's freetext form. I want to take this value and click a "submit" button to make a POST request.

It's as simple as

```
<input className="inputbox" type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Enter email..." onChange={event => this.handleInputOnChange(event)}/>
<button type="submit" className={confirmClass} onClick={this.props.handleConfirm(this.state.email)} disabled={!this.state.email}>Confirm</button>
```

Where `handleInputOnChange` is

```
handleInputOnChange(event) {
    this.setState({"email": event.target.value});
}
```

and `handleConfirm` is

```
handleConfirm = (email) => {
    http.post(someUrl + '/somefunc/', 
        {"some_email": email})
        .then((result) => {this.setState({"some_email": email})});
    window.location.reload();
  }
```

`http.post` is a custom request function that has some additional headers in it.

But now when I load the page, it goes into an infinite loop. It actually doesn't have any error message. Just keeps looping nonstop.

What's the cause of this and how do I make a POST call with what's in the input?

Comment: are you saying that the page reloads in an infinite loop?

Comment: `onClick={() => this.props.handleConfirm(this.state.email)}` should solve it. they way you wrote it the function is executed without your click

Comment: @cowCrazy, thank you so much. this solves the problem exactly! could you write a response so I can mark it as answer? Also, I'm still new to react. What's the difference between `() => func` and `func` along? You mentioned the latter would execute without any action? Why is it not causing a syntax error? It doesn't seem like this would ever be an intended reaction?

Comment: Why not just use a regular form with method="POST" if you're just going to reload the page anyways?

Comment: @JChao Done with additional explanation :)

Comment: @Bryan in react you would  normally want to have more power on the user actions. So you can validate, add info to the form etc. Only then to send it to some backend.

Comment: @cowCrazy It's not a framework specific question. I mean given the exact code above, it's a lot of extra work to do nothing more than mimic something built right into html. I would argue when you're using a js framework of any kind you should be able to update the page without reloading it. That's kind of the point of these reactive frameworks. Either way. Cheers on helping the OP solve their issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `onClick={() => this.props.handleConfirm(this.state.email)}` the event would be assigned a function that executed on the event. If you write `onClick={this.props.handleConfirm(this.state.email)}` it will be executed on the component render.

As far as I understand react and jsx every js code within the jsx would be executed. This way you get for example `<div style={{ opacity: this.state.loading ? 0.5 : 1}}>...</div>` to generate the expected div with opacity or without because the statement `this.state.loading ? 0.5 : 1` is evaluated and you see the result. Same thing when you write in your js code `myFunc()` js will call this function. So if you want to assign onClick to a function instead of calling a function you need to assign it to an anonymous function `() => {}` or in you case `() => this.props.handle()` you are assigning an anonymous function that will call another function.

Last point to the topic, if you just want to reference an existing function you can write `onClick={this.eventHandler}` and it should also work as expected.